# Mobile JQuery Auto Complete href link for search

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have mobile jquery search, my problem is for the href link search the input box doesnt have a value to search with. Only listbox with href, I wanted to used the $value in a $_POST for search in mysql.

my php code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <?php 
   include_once('database.php');
   $db = new database($con);
   $db->dbconnect(); 
   $array_names = $db->populate_li();

  ?>


<div data-role="page" id="filterMe">
  <div data-role="content">
     <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
      <?php
      foreach($array_names as $value) {
          echo "<li class='ui-screen-hidden'>"."<a href='#'>".$value ."</a></li>" .  "</br>"; }?>
    </ul>

    </div> <a href="#" data-role="button" class="val">Retrieve values</a>

   <p class="values"></p>
</div>
```